# Java - Circle Fractal

Tags: java, fractals

Please help me! I draw circle fractal but I can only draw the left side or right side. How can I draw the two sides?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXlgW.jpg)

```
public class ZZZ {
public static void main(String[] args) {
StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1024,1024);
StdDraw.setXscale(-15,15);
StdDraw.setYscale(-15,15);
double x=0.0;
double y=0.0;
double r=5.0;
StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.01);
StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
    int j=StdRandom.uniform(2);
    for(int s=1;s<10;s++){
    x=x+r;
    r=r/3*2;
    StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
    }
    int k=StdRandom.uniform(2);
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
    x=x-r;
    r=r/3*2;
    StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
    }}}
```

Comment: [Why is can somebody help me not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you forgot a question mark... that'd be why.

Comment: @Wietlol I forgot two question marks and the double quotes, if you're going to be picky.

Comment: To answer the actual question, it does render, but not where you think it does. Try resetting both X and R to their default values @AndyTurner I am not picky, Im just answering your qu... uhm... nvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset `x` back to `0` and `r` back to `5` before drawing circles in the second `for`-loop. So your code should look like following:

```
public class ZZZ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1024,1024);
        StdDraw.setXscale(-15,15);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-15,15);

        double x=0.0;
        double y=0.0;
        double r=5.0;

        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.01);
        StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);

        int j=StdRandom.uniform(2);
        for(int s=1;s<10;s++){
            x=x+r;
            r=r/3*2;
            StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
        }

        x = 0.0;
        r = 5.0;
        int k=StdRandom.uniform(2);
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
            x=x-r;
            r=r/3*2;
            StdDraw.circle(x, y, r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to do it.  I did it before, but it did not work.  I guess I'm writing wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much!!